# How to call a function within a function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to call a VBA function within another one, such as:

```
Function funcA() As String
  ' some code
Function End

Function funcB() As String
  Dim i As String
  i = funcA()
  funcB = i
Function End
```

However, when I tried to run a sub containing funcB, the invalid identifier error popped up at the position where I call funcA within funcB. What is wrong with it? Thanks!

Comment: As already mentioned you have to change  `Function End` to `End Function`. Apart from that your code works for me like it did for Gary.  I think you have to show your test code. Side note: You do usually not use `i` as a [variable name](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86904/why-do-most-of-us-use-i-as-a-loop-counter-variable/86911#86911) for a string.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
Function End
```

with:

```
End Function
```

```
Function funcA() As String
  funcA = "whatever"
End Function

Function funcB() As String
  Dim i As String
  i = funcA()
  funcB = i
End Function

Sub MAIN()
    MsgBox funcB()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a compiler error: replace Function End for `End Function`.